# Did a dust storm in Saudi Arabia cause it to "rain" money?

Tags: economics, meteorology, saudi-arabia

The report

> Video: Storm in Saudi Arabia (or Dubai) causes money to rain. [Emirates 24|7 News, February 24, 2015](http://www.emirates247.com/news/region/video-storm-in-saudi-arabia-or-dubai-causes-money-to-rain-2015-02-24-1.582033)

claims that a recent dust storm in Saudi Arabia contained, briefly, bank notes flying in the wind. NASA's Earth Observatory has taken this report at face value and [included it in its feature of the dust storm itself](http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/IOTD/view.php?id=85370), but I'm not quite sure how much to trust it. Is there additional confirmation of this event from more official sources?

Comment: Watch the story grow: NASA reports "thousands of notes", supporting with a news article that reports "hundreds of Saudi riyal notes", before given the detail of "nearly SR10,000 in SR100 notes" (i.e. less than 100 notes).

Comment: Meanwhile, the picture illustrating the report shows a [50 Saudi Riyal note](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudi_riyal#mediaviewer/File:Saudi_Riyal_5th_Domination.jpg), not SR100 note as captioned.

Comment: "From more official sources"? I don't see any reason to doubt [Emirates 24/7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emirates_24/7). It appears to be a legit news site and a [subsidiary](http://www.emirates247.com/about-us-1.108) of [Dubai Media Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubai_Media_Incorporated). The article also includes a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZxR0TK2S0o).

Comment: @coleopterist: Someone could find the source article from the Sabq newspaper, and translate, I guess. I wonder if the question is purely based on the exaggerated use of the word "rain" and "dust storm" rather than "swirled in the blustery wind in the immediate area".

Comment: It's hard to see because she keeps moving the camera from left to right, but the money could be coming out of that car to the right, with its door open.